# How to use OR in this WHERE clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'002'})-[r]-> (o:Attributes)
WHERE any(key in keys(o) 
    WHERE key CONTAINS value) 
return s, r, o
```

In the 2nd clause, I want to express either "key CONTAINS value" OR "value CONTAINS key". How to add the second possibility in this WHERE clause?

Comment: What do you mean by "wifi CONTAINS key"? There is no `wifi` variable in the query.

Comment: Please my editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `value` variable is in scope from some unseen earlier section in the query, it should be as easy as adding the OR and the predicate:

```
...
MATCH (s:Product {id:'002'})-[r]-> (o:Attributes)
WHERE any(key in keys(o) 
    WHERE key CONTAINS value OR value CONTAINS key) 
RETURN s, r, o
```